Amazon application load balancers says insecure connection
I tried creating application load balancer on port 443 using amazon on my backend server which is configured on nginx.All my health checks are working properly but when trying to test with https://dns name of loadbalancer iam getting insecure connection.How to resolve.I have created by loadbalancer by importing certs of ec2 server using letsencrypt from ACM and also made dns of hostname to point to loadbalancer dns.At my nginx ,i allowed only port 443 that also using ssl.Can we achieve this?like listening port of loadbalancer to 443 and also nginx port to listen only 443?

Please provide the exact message you are receiving (that says it is insecure) and please tell us where you are seeing this message and what you did to make it appear.

On viewing site information on Edge, firefox, and chrome web browsers address bar by giving https:// amazonloadbalancerdns, I could see not secure status.which upon clicking shows "ÿour connection to this site is not secure" .
